# assign color to follow particular order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a timeseries plot of the following sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
dates       cat dog mat sat tap 
1997-01-01  0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1
1997-01-02  0.3 0.2 0 0.5 0
1997-01-03  0.1 0 0.2 0.3 0.4
", header = TRUE,fill=TRUE)

df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, cat:tap) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area()
```

I have created a separate file and assigned a set of colors and want it to follow the order in the file.

```
col <- as.character(mycolor$color)
names(col) <- as.character(mycolor$grp)
```

However, I always get it ordered alphabetically when using `scale_fill_manual(values = col)`. What should I change here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `variable` as factor using the colors. As you do not shared `mycolor`, it must contain the same names as you reshaped values. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Colors
col <- as.character(mycolor$color)
names(col) <- as.character(mycolor$grp)
#Data and plot
df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, cat:tap) %>% 
  mutate(variable=factor(variable,levels = as.character(mycolor$grp),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col)
```

Using reproducible data on both sides:

```
#Mycolor
mycolor <- data.frame(color=c('yellow','purple','blue','pink','magenta'),
                      grp=c('tap','dog','cat','sat','mat'),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Colors
col <- as.character(mycolor$color)
names(col) <- as.character(mycolor$grp)
#Data and plot
df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, cat:tap) %>% 
  mutate(variable=factor(variable,levels = as.character(mycolor$grp),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col)
```

Output:

[image]

Now you can see how the order of `mycolor` is reflected in the final plot after using `mutate()`: